# Why are some names light blue in code markdown syntax highlighting?

Tags: discussion, python, markdown

**What is the light blue syntax highlighting?**

On BSE in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104862/15543), `IntProperty, FloatProperty, EnumProperty, MyInt, MyFloat` and `MyEnum` are syntax highlighting in light blue.

[image: image of the syntax highlighted code on BSE]

And as a supplementary, why isn't the same syntax highlighting used on meta?

Comment: looks like SE has no syntax highlighting on the meta. I guess its its that talking about the site we don't need syntax highlighting that often.

Answer (score 2):

**PEP8 style criteria.**

Quoting from the [Best Practice Style Conventions](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_best_practice.html#style-conventions)

> For Blender/Python development we have chosen to follow python
>   suggested style guide to avoid mixing styles amongst our own scripts
>   and make it easier to use python scripts from other projects.
>
> Using our style guide for your own scripts makes it easier if you
>   eventually want to contribute them to blender.
>
> This style guide is known as pep8 and can be found here
>
> A brief listing of pep8 criteria.
>
> - camel caps for class names: MyClass
> - all lower case underscore separated module names: my_module
> - indentation of 4 spaces (no tabs)
> - spaces around operators. 1 + 1, not 1+1
> - only use explicit imports, (no importing *)
> - don’t use single line: if val: body, separate onto 2 lines instead.

The syntax highlighter is using the style, and expects a [camel-case name  (CamelCase)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), for instance, `MyInt` to be a class.  Suggest naming it `my_int` or `myint` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to build on @batFINGER's answer.

StackExchange syntax highlighting is handled by **[Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)**. Looking at the source code, it appears that **Code Prettify** has a general set of rules that it enables/disables for languages with C-like syntax, making slight tweaks for individual languages. Python's configuration function is as follows:

```
registerLangHandler(sourceDecorator({
      'keywords': PYTHON_KEYWORDS,
      'hashComments': true,
      'multiLineStrings': true,
      'tripleQuotedStrings': true
    }), ['cv', 'py', 'python']);
```

This tells us that there is no special consideration given for `CamelCase`, or `snake_case`, etc. in prettifying Python. So, **Code Prettify** is not specifically following **PEP8** criterion, but rather a more general naming convention. This convention of `CamelCase` for class names is found in many **C** style guides, which I would assume **Code Prettify** is based off of.